# Django CMS: How can I show from database in setting window

Tags: django, django-cms

I want to show data in dropdown from database in setting window. Right now I am showing from hard-coded array.

```
MY_CHOICES = (
        ('a', 'Cat1'),
        ('b', 'Cat2'),
    )
    categories = models.CharField("Survey", help_text="Select Survey", choices=MY_CHOICES, max_length=3, blank=True)
```

**models.py**

```
# encoding: utf-8
from cms.models import CMSPlugin, python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from cms.models import CMSPlugin


class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.name)

    def questions(self):
        if self.pk:
            return Question.objects.filter(survey=self.pk)
        else:
            return None

class SurveyPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    MY_CHOICES = (
        ('a', 'Cat1'),
        ('b', 'Cat2'),
    )
    categories = models.CharField("Survey", help_text="Select Survey", choices=MY_CHOICES, max_length=3, blank=True)

    name = models.CharField("Survey Name", max_length=255, default='Survey Name',
                            help_text='Enter Survey Name')
    description = models.CharField("Survey Description", max_length=500, blank=True, help_text='Write Description here')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Returning some Survey Text"
```

I want to show survey in *Edit Setting* Window.

How to fill `surveys` from db value?

Comment: May be user ForeignKey Field or ManyToManyField ?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I am assuming that you want your choices to be saved into database rather than the defined tuple?

Comment: @Amar Both plugin and normal models added.

Comment: categories = models. ForeignKeyField("Survey", help_text="Select Survey",  blank=True)
Something like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135555/discussion-between-amar-and-volatil3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return (self.name)

def questions(self):
    if self.pk:
        return Question.objects.filter(survey=self.pk)
    else:
        return None

class SurveyPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    categories = models.ForeignKey("Survey", help_text="Select Survey", max_length=3, blank=True)

    name = models.CharField("Survey Name", max_length=255, default='Survey Name',
                        help_text='Enter Survey Name')
    description = models.CharField("Survey Description", max_length=500, blank=True, help_text='Write Description here')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Returning some Survey Text"
```